# Zf2 Caching difference between $cache->addItem and $cache->setItem

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, zend-framework2

I have 1000 objects, where each object needs a "key".

For example

```
$this->setItem("1", $object);
$this->setItem("2", $object);
```

My problem is that each time I use `$this->setItem()` or `$this->addItem()` Zend is creating a new folder with a `.dat` file.

I would like to create only one `.dat` file for all of the objects, however I am able to call it with `$this->getItem("key")`

Therefore, I am asking what is the difference between these two functions?

Of course I could achieve the goal with the `addItem()` function.

Comment: just checked the core zf code they do the exact same thing the exact same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of caching is to retrieve your cached results in a fast way.
If ZF2 would aggregate all your different cache keys (and their data) in a single file it would be impossible to fetch your data fast because all the expensive file searching / splitting etc. which needs to happen.
Generating a single file for each cache key makes this process simple. ZF2 will create a MD5 hash of the cache key and can directly retrieve the file with that name from the filesystem. The different directories you see are just a substring of the hash, so the amount of directories will be limited.

- `setItem` will always write data to the specified key(overwrite if data already exists).
- `addItem` will only write data if there's no data present yet.

Comment: Thank you very much Bram, now i can understand it. :)